# Unable to connect to docker daemon on Azure Windows Server 2016 machine through VSTS2017

Tags: windows, azure, docker, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a docker command from VSTS 2017 on Windows Server 2016 Azure machine, under the "Run a Docker Command" build step.
But I am getting the following error :-

> error during connect: Get
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.25/containers/json?all=1:
>   open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.

Please help me out with that.

Comment: Does VSTS 2017 means TFS 17 or Visual Studio Team Services? What's the command? What's the result if you run that command on build agent machine? Regarding TFS and VSTS vNext build, by default,  it uses service account? Does that account can run docker commnd? Deploy agent: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows

Comment: VSTS 2017 means Visual Studio Team Services.
And as mentioned, there I am adding a build step named "Run a Docker Command".

Comment: Yes, I already created the agent , but it is not giving docker as system capabilities. I have to manually add docker as capability of the VSTS agent configured.

Comment: Is it Command Line build step? What's the result if you run that command on Build agent manually?

Comment: When I ran the command directly on the Azure machine, it ran successfully. 
But when trying to run it through VSTS, I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Go to VSTS 2017.
Create a new build definition.
Add "Run a Docker Command" build step and configure the same.
Try to run the build on a default agent having Azure machine configured on it.
By this you will come to know the details of the issue.

Comment: I think you installed Docker Integration extension. How do you setup docker environment? Docker for windows or Docker Toolbox? What's the detail build log?

Comment: I have installed docker for windows.
And as I said, the docker commands are running well in my Azure machine directly.
The problem arises when I try to invoke them using VSTS as mentioned above.

Comment: Is your build agent run in interactive mode with "Administrator" permission?

Comment: Yes @Eddie-MSFT

Comment: The issue is usually related to administrator permission. Are you using this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker?

Comment: Yes @Eddie-MSFT

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT, any progress ??